# Creating a bus port in custom made part in LogicWorks

Tags: bus, logicworks

I'm creating some parts in LogicWorks and instead of having individual pins for input and output I want to use a bus pin.  I can't seem to figure out how to make the bus pins appear in the part builder.  I created a breakout in the sub-circuit to symbolize a bus, but when I go to create the part and import the sub-circuit the bus port doesnt show up.  Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured this one out.  It turns out you have to create your own bus port inputs and outputs.  It's fairly easy:

Open a new file for creating a device symbol. In
Device Symbol Editor, Choose “Set to primitive
type” in Options-> subcircuit/part
type and then choose Port Connector. The symbol
will then be of Type Port Connector.
Create a number of pins for a bus by choosing
Option->Add pins with, for example,
INPUT[A0..A3] for a four-bit input bus that has
signals A0 to A3.
The signal names must match those that the bus is
to be connected to. Therefore each bus port
connector can only be used once to connect signals
with same names.
A bus internal pin can be either output or input or bi-directional.
Set pins on a bus to be output pins if the pins are to be connected to inputs of a sub-circuit.
Draw a bus symbol that can be any
shape you want. Select a bus pin from
the symbol palette and place it on the
bus symbol. There are four bus pins,
one for each side of the bus symbol.
A screen capture on the right shows
how a 4-bit input bus port can be
created. Notice that the pin functions
are designated as Output, although the
bus port is an input bus port.
Make sure the pin directions and the
number of pins match the intended
application.
Save the port connector symbol to your
own library.

Comment: Very helpful post. Thank you. But, when you're using your new port in the sub-circuit, don't forget to give the port a name. The buss has a name. The custom port part has a label (not a name!). And, like naming the buss, you need to name the port. Otherwise, LogicWorks will give you an obscure error message when you save the sub-circuit. Moreover, LW won't be able to find the port's pins when creating the parent part. Found this out "the hard way!" I.e., expended a couple hours