# How to make a chip with lots of pins in Logicworks

Tags: digital-logic, logicworks

I'm trying to make a mux in logicworks. I was already able to make a simple one. But now I'm trying to make one that has lots of pins. There will be two sets of 32 pins for the input, a select pin, and 32 pins for the output. Is there some way I can make this simpler than having 97 pins on the outside, maybe by using buses?

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use a bus.  A bus combines multiple wires into one larger 'wire' / array.  See [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/21125/creating-a-bus-port-in-custom-made-part-in-logicworks) for adding buses to a custom part.